# Is there a way to access the source code of the DJI Pilot android application?

Tags: android, dji-sdk

I'm working on a flight planning application for use in automating drone flights for purposes of mapping(creating orthophotomosaics and 3D models). I've been able to use the DJI Mobile SDK and the DJI UX SDK for Android to create an app similar to DJI GO. However I'd like to have develop a mapping mission and oblique mission similar to the one in DJI Pilot. Instead of creating the UI elements and implementing the logic from scratch, I was wondering if there's an SDK for DJI Pilot from which I can build on?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't anything better than the uxsdk I'm aware of.
And I think ux is going end of life soon.

The source code is proprietary code. The apk's is encrypted, and it would be illegal to use any source code from it anyway.

So I think you left to implement everything from scratch.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sure the DJI uxsdk is really good but it's only useful for manual flights and I'd like to have an automated mission flight capability (waypoints, mapping, and oblique) in the application I'm developing. I'll contact DJI sales to inquire on the pricing for the source code of DJI Pilot. Thanks.

Comment: You know you have access to the waypoints api from ux?
I think your chances are slim, DJI never does anything like that. Anyway I wish you good luck :-)

Comment: I did contact them. Turns out the DJI Pilot SDK is confidential and can't be bought for confidential reasons so I just have to use the mobile SDK and the UXSDK. I've been trying out the waypoints API and I'm very hopeful this will work. What I'm not sure of is the mapping missions where a user defines an area on a map, the desired overlap etc and then the application automatically determines the flight paths for that. From a developer perspective, how can this be implemented? Are there classes for that in the mobile SDK? Any pointers will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I'm amazed you even got an answer :-)
The short answer is no. There is no help at all from the sdk, you have to do all the tiresome work yourself.
There might be some good opensource libraries you can use, I don't know.
I've switched to python, and using opensource libraries to calc distances from gps locations and similar things. You can also search for opensource sw for mapping missions with non dji drones. Might be something you can get frome there. Good luck :-)